# how can we get the absolute URL from page source while page scraping through HTML Agility?

Tags: html, html-agility-pack

I am using this code to scraping the HTML page through `HTMLAgility`. But while scraping the page, I am unable to convert relative url to absoute url.

I am using this code:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(serviceStatusHTMLURL);
data = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='columnRight']").OuterHtml;
```

I need to scrape the whole page with all HTML tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you would need to scrape all the HTML content in a single page.You can modify the second line to below code which includes all the contents of that page.

data  = doc.DocumentNode.InnerText;

Your entire page's content will come under DocumentNode